# Why does this line of localization behave this way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, expressionbuilder

I'm localizing an ASP.NET web site. Usually to localize text in an .aspx page I just use

`<%= Resources.ResourceFile.ResourceName  %>`

For asp.net controls, this won't work. I have to use the syntax

`<%$ Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceName %>`

However, if I have a button and localize the `Text` property that way, but add any additional characters after it, the localization breaks and it shows as plaintext.

So `Text="<%$ Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceName %> &raquo;"` displays as
<%$ Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceName %> »

I'm sure there is a valid reason for this, I just can't find the explanation on MSDN on how the Text property evaluates this. I'm not even 100% sure on what the `<%$` actually does.

Comment: Try putting Single quotes around it instead of double quotes. so `Text='<%$ Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceName %> &raquo;'`

Comment: @Bazzz, that didn't work. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that ASP.net is invoking an [Expression Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx). What effectively happens here is that rather than the ASP.net compiler translating your:

```
<asp:AControlWithATextProperty runat="server" Text="Some Text">
```

to:

```
AControlWithATextProperty ctl1 = new AControlWithATextProperty();
ctl1.Text = "Some Text";
```

When it transforms the markup in the `.aspx` file into a `.cs` file combined with the code-behind, it actually does something similar to this:

```
<asp:AControlWithATextProperty runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:ResourceFile, ResourceName %>">
```

Becomes:

```
AControlWithATextProperty ctl1 = new AControlWithATextProperty();
ctl1.Text = ResourceExpressionBuilder.EvaluateExpression("ResourceFile, Resourcename");
```

It would seem that the asp.net compiler can't handle concatenating the content of the `<%$ %>` tags with any further text in the property from markup. Either a bug, or by design. i.e. You don't end up with `ctl1.Text = ResourceExpressionBuilder.EvaluateExpression("ResourceFile, Resourcename") +  "&raquo;"`.

You can read more about the [ResourceExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceexpressionbuilder.aspx) on msdn, [ExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx) in general, or if you really want to; an implementation of one for localisation (database backed, hence the fact that I didn't use the ResourceExpressionBuilder) [on](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders.html) [my](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders-2--.html) [blog](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders-3--.html) (3 parts).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Out of curiosity, do you think I should file a possible bug report regarding the concatenation?

Comment: @Brandon, I'm honestly not sure, it can't hurt to raise a connect issue against this (if there's not one already) and see what the response from Microsoft is =)